# Windows Defaulting language to 'Unknown Language' Causing applications to crash on startup

Tags: windows-7, crash, input-languages, locale, language-bar

Recently I've noticed that windows seems to be defaulting by system language for all applications to 'Unknown Language':

[image: Language Bar]

This is causing some applications to crash on startup. If I quickly change the language when the app is loading it starts fine. One example is Visual Studio, I have node js tools installed, when the node js tools extension loads it crashes taking Visual Studio with it - the error message indicates that it has a problem loading the culture:

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException
Stack:
   at System.Globalization.CultureData.GetCultureData(Int32, Boolean)
```

If I start in safe mode, close the node.js tools window, and then restart the application, it loads (showing '??' in the language bar). I can then change the language back to English and open the nodejs tools window fine. After this Visual Studio will open with English as the normal language until I restart my PC.

My list of installed languages only shows English US, which is also selected as my default language:
[image]

Output of reg query "HKCU\Keyboard Layout" /s:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Preload
1    REG_SZ    00000409

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Substitutes

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Toggle
    Hotkey    REG_SZ    1
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/855465/edit)  and add output from next command `reg query "HKCU\Keyboard Layout" /s`

Comment: Added reg query output - Looks fine to me, from what I can find on google 00000409 is the US English Keyboard.

Comment: Try [sfc /scannow](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html) to check for system corruption. If nothing is found, boot in Safe mode and check if the problem still happens, to check if this is a Windows or application error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems this can be caused by this:

http://edd.stefancamilleri.com/2013/11/25/asp-net-mvc-always-throws-a-system-globalization-culturenotfoundexception/

You could try to delete all files in this folder here:

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files"
```

Or here (x64):

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files"
```

Comment: This makes no sense to me - but it works! Thanks @User0!